# Conversion from the f-string literals to format method in python

Tags: python-3.x

We have a python code base where we want to update all the python scripts which are using f string literals for string formatting to using the format method. Looking for ideas for getting it done easily.

Have tried f2format on M1 mac but it has lots of errors and it has not changed since long time. Looking for some updated projected or solution for the problem

Comment: It is a strange requirement, so maybe it is caused for other reasons, which may requires manual work (e.g. for i18n reasons, so better names arguments). In any case, I would do it with a python script and regex. It is expected that one code base has similar uses (and so not all complex and large number of options). Hopefully just few cases (or with similar rule) of escapes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty brute force approach :)
I can imagine there are many problems this code can't handle.

If you have a source file like this

```
#code.py
animal = "cat"
car = "Porsche"

print(f"This is a {animal}")
print("This is a {animal}".format(animal=animal))

print(f"This is a {animal} and a {car}")
print("This is a {animal} and a {car}".format(animal=animal, car=car))
```

Try this script

```
# fixer.py
import re


def resolve(line):
    s = re.search(r'f["\']', line)
    if s:
        cut = s.span()[0]  # location of 'f'
        ch = line[cut + 1]  # quote char
        line = line[:cut] + line[cut + 1 :]  # cut out f
        t = re.split(ch, line)
        b = re.findall(r"\{(\w+)\}", t[1])  # find the substitution names

        f = [f"{x}={x}" for x in b]
        t.insert(-1, f".format({','.join(f)})")
        t.insert(1, ch)
        t.insert(3, ch)

        return "".join(t)
    return line


with open("code.py") as f:
    text = list(map(resolve, f.readlines()))

print("".join(text))
```

output is:

```
animal = "cat"
car = "Porsche"

print("This is a {animal}".format(animal=animal))
print("This is a {animal}".format(animal=animal))

print("This is a {animal} and a {car}".format(animal=animal,car=car))
print("This is a {animal} and a {car}".format(animal=animal, car=car))
```

Comment: Currently getting this using f2format. While trying to convert whole codebase was failing but with one file at a time it is working.
https://github.com/pybpc/f2format